# How to set "selected" on the correct value Vue

Tags: python, vue.js

I have a 'problem' with a modal.
Depending on a parameter, "edit" or "new", an empty form is loaded in the modal, or, when edit, I want have all the info of the object I select to edit.

So far, so good.
However, when I want to edit, I would have the  set on the value which correcsponds with the object value.

The 'problem' I created myself is as follow:

- In the empty form, I have computed values as option.

```
<select v-model="data.categorie">
<option v-for="n in 14">Onder-{{ n + offset }}</option>
</select>
```

This is saved as a string value (e.g. "Onder-10")

When 'edit', I use the same kind of form, but now I want the "option" which is corresponding to the 'data.categorie' to have the "selected".

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this, since I use the "Onder-{{n+offset}} to populate the select/option field and is therefore not comparable....

Should I set an empty variable at  an v-bind (let's say test) it with the  and then do a

```
:selected="test === data.catagorie"
```

Or, what should be the best approach?

Comment: if the v-model matches the value of any option then the matching option will automatically be selected.  [example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kT9PwzAQxb/KyUtBtAmIslQpEqAOMFAEjF6i5BJcHNuynVIpynfnbNM/A+pm3/ud3zvfwB6MybY9sgUrXGWF8eDQ9+aeK9EZbT0MYLGBERqrO5gQOuGKq0or56EufQnLAFwMXAFUpcdWW4ELmKxVjXZ2R/R4eezQTUPv//Vck1DkyZYM6eKxM5IeoRtA4VBi5WE763SNcslZ8MsOJpxFjEBtvNCKwEZbwhQIBTdz0lOIYQAFV3vvcSzy1JBc8mRDlyI/8WdT5h2FbkSbbZxW9ENxRs4q3Rkh0a7jI46zBUQlaKWU+ucl1rztcbqvV19Yff9T37hdqHH2ZtGh3dJQB82XtkWf5NXHK+7ofBDpS3pJ9BnxHZ2WfciYsMde1RT7hItpn+OehWo/3WrnUbn9UCFoIMfIc0a7fzoz+jHubTaPfbR6Nv4CzNrLLg==)

Comment: That works like a charm. I was binding with the option instead of the select